Поиск наибольшего размера шрифта для помещения текста в область
Есть текст. В нём есть строчки. Происходит следующее: если строчка не меньше, чем w, её делят на несколько строчек короче w так, чтобы не пришлось переносить слова. Как найти максимальный размер шрифта для такой строчки, при котором количество строк, умноженное на размер шрифта, не превосходит h?
Я написал кривой алгоритм, который, по сути, сводит задачу к поиску всех таких размеров s шрифта для одной строчки, при которой шрифт на единицу меньшего размера (s-1) позволит поделить её на строчки, количество которых на одну меньше (чем со шрифтом s).
Код:
private void updateFont(){
        if(getDocument()==null)return;
        FontMetrics fm=getFontMetrics(maxFont);
        TreeSet<Integer>m=new TreeSet<Integer>();
        for(String t:getText().split("\n")){
            int r=0,l=0;
            for(String p:t.split(" ")){
                int a=fm.stringWidth(p);
                r+=a;
                if(r>getWidth()){++l;r=a;}
            }
            int b=maxFont.getSize();
            for(int i=l-1;i>0;i--){
                int a=0;
                //TODO: find optimal algorythm
            }
        }
        int l=0;
        for(int f:m){
            ++l;
            if(getHeight()/getFontMetrics(maxFont.deriveFont(f)).getHeight()>l){
                setFont(maxFont.deriveFont(f-1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }

По сути, я хочу найти максимально возможно большой шрифт такой, чтобы он уместился на JTextArea с setLineWrap(true) и setWrapStyleWords(true) притом, желательно, без перебора, но, кажется, эта задача слишком сложна для меня.
Пожалуйста, помогите найти оптимальный алгоритм.
ПРАВКА: В своём недописанном решении (см. отредактированный вопрос) я пытался обозначить "точки" (значения размеров), где количество строчек становится больше, и после этого пройтись по ним и найти максимальный допустимый.
Моё желание найти алгоритм быстрее, чем бинарный поиск обусловлено частыми вызовами метода, в котором исполняется код, и стремлением к поддержке низкопроизводительных устройств.

Количество строк зависит от размера шрифта нелинейно, но монотонно, поэтому для сокращения количества разбиений и проверок можно воспользоваться бинарным поиском по размеру шрифта.

Бинарный поиск - это тоже перебор. Он быстрее, но проверять log n, где n - количество шрифтов, всё равно долго. Обрати внимание, я просил не использовать перебор.

@TechoftheAbsence "количество шрифтов", вы ранее спрашивали об одном шрифте в разных размерах. Уточните пожалуйста, а чем вам не нравится перебор 3-5 размеров, у вас какие-то особенные ограничения или диапазон размеров от 1 до 1200 со значениями после точки?

Беда -  как я уже написал - в том, что при малом изменении шрифта количество строк может существенно измениться - перестанут влезать несколько слов, и сразу пять строк новых.. Поэтому невозможно одной формулой вычислить нужный шрифт (если только у вас не одного размера слова в строках). Подобный случай рассматривается в книге Фень Юаня по графике в Windows при определении размера шрифта для вписывания в нужный прямоугольник. И бинарный поиск - всё-таки не полный перебор.

@Kromster, прошу прощения, я имел в виду количество размеров шрифтов. Дело в том, что проверка каждого шрифта - занятие относительно небыстрое, а в случае с UI на слабых ПК это (если таких алгоритмов много) чувствительно. Очень хотел бы найти какое-то решение похитрее и побыстрее.

@MBo, я понимаю. В своём недописанном решении (см. отредактированный вопрос) я пытался обозначить "точки" (значения размеров), где количество строчек становится больше, и после этого пройтись по ним и найти максимальный допустимый. Не формула, конечно, но, вроде, уже лучше, чем многократная проверка. Я отмечу ваш ответ как полезный, но пока не приму его в поиске лучшего решения.

@TechoftheAbsence эти все уточнения желательно в тело вопроса добавить тоже. Касательно скорости, в идеале, проверка не должна касаться UI, а должна идти чисто вычислительно, т.е. очень-очень быстро. Если конечно вопрос не тексте объемом с "Войну и Мир".

@Kromster, напрямую в метод отрисовки я, конечно, этот код положить не рискну ) Однако, он лежит в методе, который вызывается практически при любом изменении компонента, вследствие чего я бы хотел избежать временных затрат. "Войну и Мир" засуну в JScrollPane. Кстати, упоминания можно не использовать, поскольку я автор вопроса и так или иначе получаю уведомления о комментариях под ним.

@TechoftheAbsence если почти каждый раз изменения небольшие, то это отправная точка для возможной стратегии - проверить текущий размер и +/-1 если не влезло или осталось "чуть-чуть", а не делать полный двоичный поиск. Также, если изменения идут пачками, то можно попробовать делать перерасчет не для каждого сразу, а через таймайт после последнего, например, 500мс. упоминания под вопросом не нужны, а вот под ответом все же вроде требуются
